# Keras AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'relu'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

When I try to use `keras` in Python, PyCharm tells me:

```
File "D:/Bitbucket/kaggle/Homesite Quote Conversion/keras_nn_test_0.96363.py", line 167, in <module>
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="sgd")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'relu'
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Please add the code causing this error to the question so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

This has been marked as an [*issue*](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/825) on their issue tracker and is caused by the fact that the version on `pip` is not the most up to date.
As most users on there suggested, re-installing theano by cloning the repository and using `setup.py` solves the issue.

P.s: It is also *explicitly* mentioned in [their installation guide](https://github.com/fchollet/keras#installation):

> Note: *You should use the latest version of Theano, not the PyPI* version. Install it with:
>
> ```
> sudo pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
> ```

Along with all other dependencies, of course.